# How to count multiple query results

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a document structure

```
var RelationshipSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  followee: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  follower: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  start: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  end: {
    type: Date
  }
})
```

If i has a userId How would i query to count the followee and the follower for the same given userId.
and return the result?

Comment: Why two references ? One is enough, since A is follower of B implies that B has A as followee.

Comment: Basically i am trying to update the users table with the amount of people he is following and his followers. I want to do this in one query